# Using ZipFile compression: An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Tags: c#, compression, zip

I'm unsure why this exception is happening after the folder contents are successfully zipped. Should this be right?

**Error**: An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Additional information: The process cannot access the file 'c:\Temp\pack.zip' because it is being used by another process.

```
    private static string directoryPath = @"c:\Temp\";
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        zipFolder(directoryPath, directoryPath+@"pack.zip");
    }

    public static void zipFolder(string targetPath, string resultPath)
    {
        ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(targetPath, resultPath,CompressionLevel.Optimal,true);
    }
```

Comment: One of the files you are attempting to zip is being accessed by another process.

Comment: Unrelated, but you should have a look at [`Path.Combine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), instead of doing string concatenation to assemble a valid path.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing in your code is reading the content of C:\Temp while trying to create a zip file in the **same** directory.

Instead create a file in the app directory and copy the file to the Temp folder later on.

```
        var newFilePath = Path.Combine(directoryPath, "pack.zip");
        if(File.Exists(newFilePath))File.Delete(newFilePath); //Remove file if it exists
        if (File.Exists("pack.zip")) File.Delete("pack.zip"); //Remove file if it exists
        zipFolder(directoryPath, "pack.zip");
        File.Move("pack.zip", newFilePath);
```